# How to prevent Image rotation when preview in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, preview, image-rotation

When a user uploads an image then it gets rotated when preview with jQuery,
here is the code:

```
    function readURL(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('.profile_img img').attr('src', e.target.result);
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }


    $("#file").change(function(){
        readURL(this);
    });
```

but when I preview the image then it rotates it, how to avoid this?

Comment: you are uploading a image,after that you rotate it, and in the preview you receive the unrotated image?

Comment: i never rotate it, infact the image gets rotated by -90 automatically, i just want to prevent it,

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle demo

Comment: can you provide the css for `.profile_img img`